# python script windows path

Tags: python, windows

I have a python script that doesn't seem to be opening the files.
The folder in the script is defined like this:

```
logdir = "C:\\Programs\\CommuniGate Files\\SystemLogs\\"
submitdir = "C:\\Programs\\CommuniGate Files\\Submitted\\"
```

This is how the paths are being used:

```
        filenames = os.listdir(logdir)
        fnamewithpath = logdir + fname
```

I'm running this script in Windows 7 sp1
Does this look correct?
Is there something I can put into the code to debug it to make sure the files are opening?

Thank you,

Docfxit

Edited to provide more clarification:

The actual code to open and close the file is here:

```
# read all the log parts
for fname in logfilenames :
    fnamewithpath = logdir + fname

    try :
        inputFile = open(fnamewithpath, "r")

    except IOError as reason :
        print("Error: " + str(reason))
        return

    if testing :
        print("Reading file '%s'" % (fname))

    reporter.munchFile(inputFile)
    inputFile.close()

# open output file
if testing :
    outfilename = fullLognameWithPath + ".summary"
    fullOutfilename = outfilename

else :
    outfilename = submitdir + "ls" + str(time.time()) + "-" + str(os.getpid())
    fullOutfilename = outfilename + ".tmp"

try :
    outfile = open(fullOutfilename, "w")

except IOError :
    print("Can't open output file " + fullOutfilename)
    return

if not testing :

    # add the mail headers first
    outfile.write("To: " + reportToAddress + "\n")
    outfile.write("From: " + reportFromAddress + "\n")
    outfile.write("Subject: CGP Log Summary new for " + logname + "\n")

    if useBase64 :
        outfile.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n")
    outfile.write("\n")

# save all this as a string so that we can base64 encode it
outstring = ""
outstring += "Summary of file: " + fullLogname + partAddendum + "\n"
outstring += "Generated " + time.asctime() + "\n"
outstring += reporter.generateReport()

if useBase64 :
    outstring = base64.encodestring(outstring)
outfile.write(outstring)
outfile.close()

if not testing :
    # rename output file to submit it
    try :
        os.rename(outfilename + ".tmp", outfilename + ".sub")
    except OSError :
        print("Can't rename mail file to " + outfilename + ".sub")
```

I was originally wondering if the double back slashes included in the path were correct.
I can't figure out why it isn't producing the output correctly.

Just in case someone would like to see the entire script I posted it:
The first half is at:

http://pastebin.ws/7ipf3

The second half is at:

http://pastebin.ws/2fuu3n

It was too large to post all in one.

This is being run in Python 3.2.2

Thank you very much for looking at it,

Docfxit

Answer (score 0):

The code as written above does not actually open either file.

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of the files (technically **entries**, as non-files like `.` and `..` are also included) in the specified path, but does not actually open them. For that you would need to call the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function on one of the paths.

If you wanted to open all the files in `filenames` for *write*, you could do something like this:

```
fileList = []
for f in filenames:
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        fullPath = os.path.join(logdir, f)
        fileList.append(open(fullPath, 'w')
```

After this, the list `fileList` would contain the open file handles for all of the files, which could then be iterated over (and, for example, all written to if you wanted to multiplex the output).

Note that when done, you should loop through the list and explicitly `close` them all (the `with` syntax that automatically closes them has additional complexities/limitations when it comes to dynamically sized lists, and is best avoided here, IMO).

For more info on files, see:
[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Also, it's best to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine components of a path. That way it can be portable across supported platforms, and will automatically use the correct path separators, and such.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

I would recommend you step through the code using a debugger to see exactly what's going wrong. I use [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), which is an enhanced command-line debugger, and find it invaluable. You can install it via *pip* into your system/*virtualenv* Python environment.

Comment: Maybe better to do "if os.path.isfile(fullPath)" ??

Comment: In production code, probably. The original example was an off-the-cuff one for illustrative purposes, but I've edited it for clarity.

Comment: I have added clarification to original post.

Comment: Thank you for the information... Do you by chance know how I can run pudb in Windows 7 or do you know of another good debugger for Windows 7?

Comment: You can use the built-in *pdb*. It's much more primitive than *pudb*, but it does run. There's also *Winpdb*; I've not tried that one.